# How to iterate over combinations of a string

Tags: c

Given a string 'string', for example, I would like to get the following while iterating: 'string', 'strin', 'tring', 'stri', 'trin, 'ring', 'str', ... , 'i', 'n', 'g'.

Comment: What is your outputs? What did you find in your debugging?

Answer (score 3):

```
char str[] = "string";
int len = strlen(str);
for(int s_len = len; s_len > 0; --s_len)
    for(int start = 0; start + s_len <= len; ++start)
        printf("%.*s\n", s_len, str + start);
```

Comment: I'd not known about the `*` format in printf() until today... Cool!

Answer (score 1):

How about the following using strncpy() and memset() from the string library:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char str[] = "string";
    int len = strlen(str);
    int sz = len + 1;
    char cpy[sz];
    for (int i=0; i<len; ++i)
        for (int j=i; j<len; ++j)
            printf("%s\n", strncpy(memset(cpy, 0, sz), &str[i], len-j));
}
```

Output:

```
string
strin
stri
str
st
s
tring
trin
tri
tr
t
ring
rin
ri
r
ing
in
i
ng
n
g
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution with snprintf() and puts():

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char str[] = "string";
    int len = strlen(str);
    int sz = len + 1;
    char cpy[sz + 1]; /* sz of str + 1 (for '\n') */
    for(int i=0; i<sz; ++i)
        for(int j=i; j<len; ++j) {
            snprintf(cpy, sz-j, "%s\n", &str[i]);
            puts(cpy);
        }
}
```

Output:

```
string
strin
stri
str
st
s
tring
trin
tri
tr
t
ring
rin
ri
r
ing
in
i
ng
n
g
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know simpler way. But to store iterations you can use `sprintf`. This is similar to `printf` but prints output to string.

Check this:

```
char buf[33]="";
for (i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
{
   for (j = 0; j <= i; j++)
   {
    for (k = j; k < j+strlen(str) - i; k++)
    {
        sprintf(buf+strlen(buf), "%c", str[k]);
        //printf("%c", str[k]);
    }
    buf[strlen(buf)] = '\0'; //adding null terminate
    printf("%s", buf);
    buf[0] = '\0'; //terminating from begining to reuse buf
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```